# Can I name my daughter Inaya Anam?

Tags: muslim-practices, naming, names

We are planning to name my new born daughter as Inaya Anam. Inaya means care and protection. And Anam means Allah's creation/Allah's blessings.
Is this a good name? Please guide.

Answer (score -1):

Congratulations to you and your wife.

Welcome to the world, Inaya.

There is a story (I can’t recall its source) of a man who complained long – and bitterly – to the Exalted about the amount of suffering in the world.  He wanted to know why the Exalted had not done anything about it.

Allāh (subḥānahu ūta'āla) answered: ‘I have.  I created you!’

In surah ‘Ash-Sharh (‘The Consolation’), Allāh (subḥānahu ūta'āla) says: ‘So truly where there is hardship there is also ease; truly where there is hardship there is also ease’.

We are created to provide ease – care and protection – to those who suffer hardship.  By so doing, we bring Allāh (subḥānahu ūta'āla)’s blessings upon them.

With this in mind, I believe you have given your daughter a most excellent name.

May Allāh (subḥānahu ūta'āla) guide Inaya throughout her life, and help her to be a consolation – and source of joy – for others.